# How to show next ul li element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I work with dynamical creation of elements.

So I have a list of 16 values, which is generated from array.Then, I build a list of **ul** elements(tabs) based on the above array.
Now I need to show only 10 tabs at a time in my HTML page.

Below function creates a **ul** element(tab) and appends inside **#left-tabs** div. This is called inside a loop with array values as input:

```
function createTab(index){
  var result = index + 1;
  var tabs = ` <ul>
                 <li value="${result}">${result}</li>
               </ul>`
  $("#left-tabs").append(tabs)
}
```

Below script is creating 16 tabs instead of 10 at a time.

```
var elements = $("#left-tabs");
var showNext = function (index2) {
        if (index2 >= elements.length) {
            index2 = 0;
            location.reload();
        }
        elements.hide().slice(index2, index2 + 10).show();
        setTimeout(function () {
            showNext(index2 + 10);    
        }, 3000);
    }
    showNext(0);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="left-tabs">
</div>
```

But for some reason it's not working.

**EDIT:**
Line `var elements = $("#left-tabs");` is pointing to parent div instead of list of tabs. Modify this line as below to make it work as expected.

```
var elements = $("#left-tabs ul");
```

Comment: Not working in what way? Do you get an error in the console?

Comment: @BrettGregson nope, i didn't have any error, this func fro some reason just not working

Comment: "_just not working_" is not a problem description. What you want your code to do, and what it does instead?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, but have a look at this based on your code: https://jsfiddle.net/gp0rwasb/ Your `$("#left-tabs")` is selecting the parent element, not the appended elements

Comment: you should somehow trigger your function. for example if you have a button add this in the html onclick="showNext(0)".

Comment: @Teemu so, i have 16 HTML element whic are build from loop. but i want to show only 10, and after some period for ex 3sec, show next 10 or in my case show rest 6

Comment: Move `var elements = $("#left-tabs");` *inside* the shownext function.  If your items are generated dynamically, this will not be updated to match the new tabs so will be out of date / empty.

Answer (score 0):

Line `var elements = $("#left-tabs")` is pointing to parent Div instead of inner **ul** elements(tabs). So first you should get list of all **ul** elements inside **left-tabs** and then iterate across them.
Modify above line as below:

```
var elements = $("#left-tabs ul");
```